# gnome-terminal: Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect: No such file or directory

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, proxy

If I run

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

then I suddenly can't run gnome-terminal. I get the error

> Error constructing proxy for
> org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect: No
> such file or directory

system I'm on:

```
wsl --version
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2359

Ubuntu 23.04
```

Is there a way to fix that ?

I can run gnome-terminal with the command

```
dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

BUT I use to launch terminal from **nautilus** so dbus-launch doesn't help there.